# Retrieve Profile from LinkedIn API by URL

Tags: api, linkedin-api

As the [API suggests](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-api) I should be able to access my  (or any other person's) profile information using public profile URL. However, using the [Rest console](https://developer.linkedin.com/rest-console) I haven't been able to get the correct result.

I've tried both of these:
`http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.linkedin.com%2fpub%2falireza-noori%2f51%2fa99%2fba9`

`http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.linkedin.com%2fpub%2falireza-noori%2f51%2fa99%2fba9:public`

None of them worked. The result is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<error>
  <status>401</status>
  <timestamp>1348521763449</timestamp>
  <request-id>6MGM1IK1U7</request-id>
  <error-code>0</error-code>
  <message>[unauthorized]. OAU:w_vW1JF73R-J97_wH3_Iut3i7kL9netWMe90_OMcAkI9mVWggQzip-ssCmwKWyJU|*01|*01|*01:1348521763:ZN/JXOqHRNm4wKsDX+vzlbSC3yY=</message>
</error>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an issue with the REST Console:

https://developer.linkedin.com/comment/16197#comment-16197